# .onTapGesture doesn't work on Stepper, only on its text - iOS 15

Tags: swift, swiftui

The `.onTapGesture` below only gets called when I tap on the text "Min. amount: $0.01", but when I tap the + or - it doesn't. How can I get it to work on the + or - as well?

I tried setting a frame below the Stepper with:

`.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)`

or setting the foreground color but made no difference. Any idea?

[image]

Its code:

```
@ViewBuilder var minCoinAmount: some View {
    // Min coin amount
    Stepper(value: $smallBalanceLimitDefinedByUser,
            in: range,
            step: step) {
        // Separated in two texts so it can be localized properly
        HStack {
            Text("Min. amount:")
            Text(utils.formatDoubleTo2DigitsString(amount: smallBalanceLimitDefinedByUser))
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm calling it with:

```
minCoinAmount
    .disabled(true)
    .onTapGesture {
        // Presents the Premium page
        storeViewModel.premiumIsPresented.toggle()
    }
```

Comment: Try putting the `.onTapGesture` on the `Stepper` itself, and again on the `HStack` if needed (rather than putting it on the entire view). As a last resort, you could put a clear color over the view, and use the tap gesture on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add hit test area with contentShape modifier, like

```
.contentShape(Rectangle())    // << here !!
.onTapGesture {
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

Comment: Side note, this does not work on iOS 16. I've modified the title to be iOS 15 only